# C# Growing List and Pointers to Elements

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, dynamic, element

I need to have a growing array, or list (the built in ones are sufficient). Furthermore I need to be able to manipulate elements in the array with pointers to that specific element for example the following code

```
List<int> l1=new List<int>();

List<bool> l2=new List<bool>();

l1.Add(8);

l2.Add(true);

l1.Add(234);

l2.Add(true);

Console.WriteLine(l1[0]); //output=8

int* pointer = (int *) l1[0];

Console.WriteLine(*pointer); //Needs to output 8

Console.WriteLine(l2[0]); //output=true

bool* pointer2 = (bool *) l2[0];

Console.WriteLine(*pointer2); //Needs to output true
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why does `Console.WriteLine(pointer);` need to output 8? shouldn't it output the value of the pointer itself?

Comment: rather than ask for a solution to a percieved problem, how about telling us what you are really actually to do?

Comment: I dont think you can do this unless you use `ToArray()`, but still you won't be manipulating the list

Comment: I don't get it. Why would you want to manipulate elements with pointers? Why write `Console.WriteLine(pointer);` instead of simply `Console.WriteLine(l1[0]);`? Can you be more explicit? Perhaps show an example that makes it obvious why you need pointers?

Comment: Im trying to use an array to store packet data and pass it off to threads, these theads need to be able to modify the data without trashing the array. I meant to have *pointer in the writelines. I need a list because I dont know how many packets there will be ahead of time

Comment: @Brandon: can't you just pass the list and indices along? What do you mean with "trashing the array"? That won't be a problem with well-behaved threads.

Comment: @Mitch: I like this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: I admit, I had to laugh. You want to *prevent* trashing the array, but then you use *pointers*. :-D Pointers will trash your whole system. That’s why they’re called unsafe.

Comment: I suppose if you have no experience with pointers, you could trash your system with it.

Answer (score 4):

> Im trying to use an array to store packet data and pass it off to threads, these theads need to be able to modify the data without trashing the array

In this case, I would just pass your `List<T>` into the threaded routine, as well as a starting and ending index that thread should use.

Provided you always work by index, and stay within the bounds, there shouldn't be any problem with "trashing the array."

Answer (score 2):

First off: you are applying a C++ approach to a problem that is solved differently in C#.  In C# you generally don't want to do things involving explicit pointers, because they make life difficult, especially as it pertains to garbage collection.

That said, if you *must* do it this way, what you'd want to do is pass the entire list (and maybe the index) as a parameter, along with an offset, to the other thread.  You would also want to be sure to [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the list appropriately in all accessing threads, to avoid dirty reads/writes.

The right solution is just to pass the item that you actually want to process.  Reference types are passed byval, but that just means a new pointer is created to the same heap variable.  It isn't actually creating a new value on the heap.

So for example:

```
var myList = new List<MyClass> { someInstanceofMyClass1, someInstanceofMyClass2 };
var t = new Thread(()=> SomeMethod(myList[0])); // Assuming MyClass is a reference type, the value passed here is the same instance as the one in myList
t.Start(); 
...
```

Comment: FYI - Locking is unnecessary (with `List<T>`) providing you're always accessing your own indices (no two threads use the same indices), and not calling Add().

Comment: True.  But locking is necessary if the threads are adding/removing items, which I am assuming they are here.

Answer (score 1):

It already works the way you want for reference types.  Therefore one potential solution is to create a class to box these values as reference types.  If the items are related by index (and I suspect they are) it's a good idea to keep one list to hold a type that groups both values rather than two lists anyway.  Going with that:

```
public Class MyClass
{
     public int IntValue {get;set;}
     public bool BoolValue {get;set;}
     public MyClass(int intValue, bool boolValue)
     {
          IntValue = intValue;
          boolValue = boolValue;
     }
}

List<MyClass> l1 = new List<MyClass>();
l1.Add(new MyClass(8, true));

MyClass pointer = l1[0];

Console.WriteLine(pointer.IntValue); //writes 8
Console.WriteLine(pointer.BoolValue); //writes True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4, you might want to look into the classes in [System.Collections.Concurrent namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx). They provide thread-safe data structures that might help you achieve your goal with less code.

Answer (score -1):

For what you are trying to accomplish (network packets), it sounds like you would benefit from a [System.IO.BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) instead of a List. (You could even pass a NetworkStream to a BinaryWriter)

It supports seeking so you can go back and re-write, and you can't trash the array since it grows automatically.

Performance-wise, I would assume BinaryWriter is faster than a List since it writes to an underlying Stream and MemoryStream is faster than a `List<byte>`

Comment: "Im trying to use an array to store packet data and pass it off to threads, these theads need to be able to modify the data without trashing the array. I meant to have *pointer in the writelines. I need a list because I dont know how many packets there will be ahead of time".

Did you read the comments?